# 2 div inline too big to fit

Tags: html, css

I got 2 main div that i'm trying to make appear on the same line. I'm struggling with the CSS to get what I want.

First div is a kind of menu, displaying categories. I can have more or less of them (should be dynamic). Second div is displaying main buttons/shortcuts and is static.

### Goal:

- both div on same line
- second div (button-container) taking 25% of the page on the right
- first div (category-container) taking whatever is left, on the left of the page. Overflow hidden, size of each indivual cells will be adjusted with javascript so everything can fit.

```css
section.home {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
section.home > div.category-container {
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline;
}
section.home > div.buttons-container {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
section.home > div.category-container > ul > li {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.category {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #aaa;
  background: White none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.category > div.category-title {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: rgb(254, 107, 3);
  font-weight: bold;
}
div.category > a > img {
  width: 200px;
}
div.category_content {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <div class="category-container">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <div class="category">
          <div class="category-title">
            <span class="font_16">Title 1</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
          </a>
          <div class="category-content">
            sutcategory1
            <br/>subcategory2
            <br/>subcategory 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="category">
          <div class="category-title">
            <span class="font_16">Title 2</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
          </a>
          <div class="category-content">
            sutcategory1
            <br/>subcategory2
            <br/>subcategory 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="category">
          <div class="category-title">
            <span class="font_16">Title 3</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
          </a>
          <div class="category-content">
            sutcategory1
            <br/>subcategory2
            <br/>subcategory 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-container">
    Buttons container
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is your goal then?

Comment: If you find your answer, don't forget to accept it as the correct one.

Comment: If an answer fits your requirement, please accept it and close the question. If not please comment what's missing.

Comment: i did accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By adding `float: left;` to the `.category-container` you are able to format the div's side-by-side.**

```
section.home>div.category-container {
    width: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline;
    float: left; /* Float left is what you need */
}
```

---

I've updated your HTML & CSS with this edit:

```css
section.home {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
section.home > div.category-container {
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
section.home > div.buttons-container {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
section.home > div.category-container > ul > li {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.category {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #aaa;
  background: White none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.category > div.category-title {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: rgb(254, 107, 3);
  font-weight: bold;
}
div.category > a > img {
  width: 200px;
}
div.category_content {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <div class="category-container">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <div class="category">
          <div class="category-title">
            <span class="font_16">Title 1</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
          </a>
          <div class="category-content">
            sutcategory1
            <br/>subcategory2
            <br/>subcategory 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="category">
          <div class="category-title">
            <span class="font_16">Title 2</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
          </a>
          <div class="category-content">
            sutcategory1
            <br/>subcategory2
            <br/>subcategory 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="category">
          <div class="category-title">
            <span class="font_16">Title 3</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
          </a>
          <div class="category-content">
            sutcategory1
            <br/>subcategory2
            <br/>subcategory 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-container">
    Buttons container
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: yes i think that's the trick. It works on fiddle but on my project my category overflow appear on the next line, even when I add some nowrap and hidden overflow everywhere....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `ul`, setting it to `inline-block` does the trick.
It crashed for small windows, because `.category` has a fixed width.

```
section.home > div.category-container UL {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
section.home {
  white-space:nowrap;
}

section.home > div.category-container {
  width:70%;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline;
}

section.home > div.category-container UL {
  display: inline-block;
}

section.home > div.buttons-container {
  width:25%;
  height:300px;
  display:inline;
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
}

section.home > div.category-container > ul >  li {
  padding-right:15px;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.category {
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow:0 3px 5px #aaa;
  background:White none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div.category > div.category-title {
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
  color:rgb(254,107,3);
  font-weight:bold;
}

div.category > a > img {
  width:200px;
}

div.category_content {
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <div class="category-container">
    <ul>
      
      <li>
        <div class="category">
          <div class="category-title">
            <span class="font_16">Title 1</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
          </a>
          <div class="category-content">
            sutcategory1<br/>
            subcategory2<br/>
            subcategory 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="category">
          <div class="category-title">
            <span class="font_16">Title 2</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
          </a>
          <div class="category-content">
            sutcategory1<br/>
            subcategory2<br/>
            subcategory 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="category">
          <div class="category-title">
            <span class="font_16">Title 3</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
          </a>
          <div class="category-content">
            sutcategory1<br/>
            subcategory2<br/>
            subcategory 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-container">
    Buttons container
  </div>
</section>
```